# how to convert file in pdf and download in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, html-to-pdf, react-pdf, react-native-pdf

I am trying to convert in pdf and download to my phone . I am trying below example .
I have done npm i react-native-html-to-pdf
and below code .
But after presing "Download Receipt"  it is coming to the fucntion but after that app is getting crash .
Please help me . What is the best solution in react native for this

```
import RNHTMLtoPDF from 'react-native-html-to-pdf';

     async createPDF() {
        let options = {
          html: '<h1>PDF TEST</h1>',
          fileName: 'test.pdf',
          directory: 'Documents',
        };
    
        let file = await RNHTMLtoPDF.convert(options)
        console.log("file name ",file);
        //console.log(file.filePath);
        //alert(file.filePath);
      }


<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.createPDF()} style={{ flex: 1, marginTop: hp(2) }}>
                  <RegularText text='Download Receipt' textColor={signatureStartColor} style={{ fontSize: hp('2%'), textAlign: 'center' }} />
                </TouchableOpacity>
```